# Add content on uib-tooltip-html dynamically

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to combine content on a uib-tooltip-html like the following example

```
 app.controller("testController", function($scope, $http, $interval, $sce) {
      $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>Some text</div>');
    });

 <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-html="<div>text moretext</div>" >
    A Thing With an HTML Tooltip
</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KWoByXuzejuRwmFmwgqJ?p=preview
is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
uib-tooltip-html="'<div>'+'text moretext'+'</div>'"
```

inside your code.

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to dynamically update the tooltip, but I can't figure out how to use a function with parameters.
So I did this:

**View**

```
<td ng-mouseover="getTooltip(model)" data-uib-tooltip-html="tooltip" ..>{{ some.data }}</td>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.tooltip = '';
$scope.getTooltip = function(model) {
     var tooltip;
     if(model.somedata == 'x') {
          tooltip = 'some content';
     }
     else {
          tooltip = 'some other content';
     }
     $scope.tooltip = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>'+tooltip+'</div>');
}
```

hope it helps someone.

Comment: Excellent solution!  There were some examples here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4738 but I couldn't get any to work.  Thank you!